# Overflow Label and TextBox together in ToolBar

Tags: wpf, xaml, toolbar

I want to create a WPF Toolbar. The ToolBar has TextBox to enter values, and right before the TextBox a Label for this TextBox.

Now I have the Problem, if the Window is resized and the TextBox doesn't fit on the Toolbar anymore, it is moved to the Overflow area, but the Label is not. This situation is undesirable. I want that either both elements are on the toolbar or both elements are on the overflow area.

How can I realize this?

I already tried putting both elements inside any Container (a DockPanel for instance). That works, but it breaks the Design. Meaning the TextBox Text is not in the same line anymore as are the other Elements in the ToolBar.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="25" Fill="{StaticResource DataGriddHeaderColor}" Margin="10,2"/>
            <ToolBar Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White">

         //YOUR TOOBAR CONTENT HEAR
            </ToolBar>

//YOUR LABEL
<Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

//YOUR TEXTBOX
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource SearchMetroTextBox}" Width="250" Height="23" Margin="10,0"
                     MinHeight="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Search term here" TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged"/>
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put them into an horizontal StackPanel and adjust the vertical/horizontal alignement properties and margin property to resolve your broken design problem.